# Overriding Bootstrap dropdown style

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to extend this custom component example http://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/ by adding appropriate style to dropdown element.

```
  <li class="dropdown masthead-dropdown">
                                <a class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Media<span class="caret"></span></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
```

CSS:

```
.masthead-dropdown{
background-color: transparent !important;
border-color:white !important;}
```

Custom styles are included after bootstrap.css, but they doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried applying them to `.dropdown.masthead-dropdown`?

Answer (score 1):

Going by the Cover menu list, I used it to guess the part of your code since I don't know what is wrapping the `<li>`:

```
    <div class="masthead clearfix">
  <div class="inner">
    <h3 class="masthead-brand">Cover</h3>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
        <li><ul class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Media
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pictures</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then add to your CSS:

```
 .dropdown-toggle {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}
```

And you can change the dropdown background colors with this:

```
.dropdown-menu{
  background-color: #000;
}
```

And the links font color:

```
.dropdown-menu>li>a{
  color: #fff;
}
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttvxx80z/6/)**